# getting version of HP system management home page version using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have more than 400 servers where "HP system management home page" installed. I need to get the version of HP system management home page on each server probably using powershell.

In the each server locally i can see the version by executing a command (getshmlogreader --version).
The path of the command "getshmlogreader" is " C:\hp\hpsmh\bin ".

When i try it with powershell using invoke-command its not working .

invoke-command -computername myserver

Please help me on this matter ...

Comment: How isn't it working? Is there an error or some other output you can share?

Comment: Perhaps as well the exact code you are using.

Comment: i get the error as follows
[myserver] Connecting to remote server myserver failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect
to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting
requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly
IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and
configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more i

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-command -ScriptBlock  { "C:\hp\hpsmh\bin\getshmlogreader.exe --version" } -computername myserver
```